Heroku deploy error: no module error and return self.load_wsgiapp()
I made a project using Python 3.12 and got it to work locally. Now I'm trying to deploy it on Heroku and it gives this even though I've installed all the requirements. It also says no module named config found.
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801570+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801570+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801570+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801571+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801571+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801571+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801571+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801572+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801572+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801573+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801573+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801574+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801574+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801574+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801575+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801575+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801575+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801575+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801575+00:00 app[web.1]: from project import app
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801576+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/project/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801576+00:00 app[web.1]: from config import Config
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801576+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
2024-04-06T17:14:44.801637+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-06 17:14:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802387+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-06 17:14:44 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802388+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802389+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802390+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802390+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802391+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802391+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802392+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802392+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802392+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802392+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802393+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802396+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802397+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802397+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802397+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802398+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802398+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802398+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802399+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802399+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802400+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802400+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802401+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802401+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802401+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802402+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802402+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802402+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802402+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802403+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802403+00:00 app[web.1]: from project import app
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802403+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/project/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802403+00:00 app[web.1]: from config import Config
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802403+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
2024-04-06T17:14:44.802492+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-06 17:14:44 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.867001+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-06 17:14:44 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) exited with code 3
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870389+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-06 17:14:44 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) exited with code 3
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870435+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870437+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870661+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870698+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870802+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870966+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.870976+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871052+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871077+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871180+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871223+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871228+00:00 app[web.1]:
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871247+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871247+00:00 app[web.1]:
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871247+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871248+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871353+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871407+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871419+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871520+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871568+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871694+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871714+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871769+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871791+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871875+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871908+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2024-04-06T17:14:44.871995+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872013+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 396, in stop
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872098+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872117+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872182+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872199+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872299+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2024-04-06T17:14:44.872330+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2024-04-06T17:14:44.948062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-04-06T17:14:44.971192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

I was trying to run my website on Heroku and it gave me module import errors. I have no idea where to look.

What's in your top-level project/__init__.py? Where is config supposed to come from? Are you using a framework? If so, which one?

@Chris; Im using flask. the init.py has some imports, and registers some routes and this  app = Flask(__name__) app.config.from_object(Config) i run the app with run.py. and theres a config.py that has a config class and gets environment variables from a .env file

Thank you for the help. I've managed to fix this issue. It had something to do with some dependency not being installed. Also, I didn't update my requirements.txt by using pip freeze > requirements.txt before deploying it to Heroku.
